# In bash, what does dir=${0%/*} means?

Tags: bash, shell, glob, parameter-expansion

I have found this piece of code while studying a bash script:

```
dir=${0%/*}
```

I suspect the code inside the braces to be regex but I don't see what it means.  Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a regex, but it is a [pattern](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) match.  It sets `dir` to the name of the script, which is `$0`, but without the last slash and any non-slash after it, if there is a slash in `$0`.  If there is no slash in `$0`, `dir` gets a copy of `$0` unchanged.  See ["Parameter Expansion"](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) in the Bash Hackers Wiki.